# How to waiting thread completed in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading

I create two thread to get a table and a function `ExcelSave(DataTable, nameofSheetinExcel)` to save all DataTable to Excel base on a name of Thread.

I want to wait for first thread save completed and go to the second thread to save.

I create two thread:

```
var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RegisterInfo))
{
    Name = "Thread1"
};
t1.Start();

var t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RegisterInfo))
{
    Name = "Thread2"
};
t2.Start();
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

My code to save file excel like this:

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Thread1")
        ExcelSave(dt, "Thread 1");
else
        ExcelSave(dt, "Thread 2");
```

Because I have exception:

> Error when saving file because the process cannot access the file 'D:\lapproject\bin\Debug\data.xlsx' because another process is using it. System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}`

Have any method to avoid this? Thanks for all people.

Comment: Are you writing to the same file? Is the file open already? Why use multiple threads in the first place?

Comment: You cannot write to excel file from multiple threads at the same time, lock it.

Comment: You can, but not using a single instance of Excel and one file to write to. There are more ways to write Excel files, including some managed libraries, like EPPlus. @Stanley

Comment: I write at same file, it only different "sheet".

Comment: Thanks for all. Simple is create a new file and save to another file. All comment suggest for two files instead of using the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following methods to prevent access the shared resource by a multiple thread at a same time and it will manage your error.

1. Use mutex class to handle the code:

   ```
   private readonly Mutex m = new Mutex();
   public void ThreadSafeMethod() {
       m.WaitOne();
       try {
           /*excel related critical code */
       } finally {
           m.ReleaseMutex();
       }
   }
   ```

2. use lock method:

   ```
   private readonly object syncLock = new object();

   public void ThreadSafeMethod() {
       lock(syncLock) {
           /*excel related critical code */
       }
   }
   ```